# logo coming out of the background color and the text color is always black

Tags: c#, html, css

I am trying to show a logo and a text side by side in an outlook page. I have a picture and logo on an HTML page. When I send the content of the HTML page to the MS outlook, the page looks different. I am not using any flexbox in my HTML code, but outlook translates it differently. I am not sure what stylesheet, I can change to make the logo and text same as HTML. Below is the HTML page:

[image]

and below is what the logo and text looks like in the outlook:

[image]

The picture protrudes outside the blue background color and the second text: "This is text2" is black color. Although, I specified in my code that second text is white color. How can I fix this issue. below is my style sheet and HTML code:

```css
        .logo {
                transform: translateX(2em);
            }
            .name1 {
                font-size: 25px;
                color: #e9c46a;
            }
    
            .name2 {
                font-size: 25px;
                color: #ffffff;
            }
    
            .container {
              
                
                padding-bottom: 40px;
               
            }
    
                .container img {
                    width: 50px;
                    height: 50px;
                }
    
            .small-image img {
                width: auto;
                height: 40px;
            }
    
            .collapse-border table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border-spacing: 0;
            }
    
            .font-aligned .name1 {
                vertical-align: bottom;
            }
    
            .font-aligned .name2 {
                vertical-align: top;
            }
```

```html
<div class="container">
                <table style="background-color: cadetblue;width:100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="3" width="100">
                            <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" class="logo" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="name1" >This is Text1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="name2">This is Text2</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

below is the C# code that sends the HTML to outlook:

```
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test", EmailPass);
        client.Port = 200;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        
         MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
       
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.From = test;

        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("t@t.com"));
        mail.Subject = "test";
        using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/EmailTemplate.html")))
        {
            body = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        mail.Body = body;

        client.Send(mail);
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to fix the issue with the image height... If yes then try this one

```
/* Use claas name or the selector I'm using img */
img {
    width: 2rem; /* 16 * 2 = 32px */
    height: 2rem;
    
    /* Use one that suits you */
    object-fit: contain;
    /* Or */
    object-fit: cover;

    /* MDN Docs -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit */
}
```